# Custom UIControl with UILabel dimming on tint color change

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uicontrol

In case of UISegmentedControl, once a popover or alert is present, the Control dims to grey (desaturates the tint color)

I'am building my own UIControl subclass, which uses a UILabel as a subview

i want to dim (desaturate) the text color of the UILabel, same way as by UISegmentedControl or (UIButton...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the `tintColor` and `tintAdjustmentMode` properties on UIView (available since iOS 7) and the `tintColorDidChange` method.

If you override them in your custom view you can respond to being dimmed out.

As the [iOS 7 UI Transitioning Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html) says:

> When an alert or action sheet appears, iOS 7 automatically dims the tint color of the views behind it. To respond to this color change, a custom view subclass that uses `tintColor` in its rendering should override `tintColorDidChange` to refresh the rendering when appropriate.

The solution may look like this :

```
- (void)tintColorDidChange {

    self.titleLabel.textColor = self.tintColor;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer did help me, the result was that the dimmed color was applied to my control even when the screen was not dimmed. I fixed this in the following manner:

```
override func tintColorDidChange() {
    switch tintAdjustmentMode {
    case .Dimmed:
        myLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    default:
        myLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}
```

This correctly applies a gray color to the control only if the screen is dimmed.